Weird math error using floating point arithmetic in C
I'm trying to extract the first digit of an integer. For that I take the number, divide it by 10, and then subtract the integer part of that number, resulting in only the decimal part, which is then multiplied by 10, and voila, the first digit of the integer.
Now the problem. The code works for all digits except 2 and 7, giving 1 and 6 respectively as result. I imagine it is related to floating point errors, like it represents 0.2 and 0.7 as 0.19999 and 0.69999. When debugging it shows the correct values but the final result is incorrect. I'm not sure how to solve or approach this issue, any help is welcomed. Thanks beforehand.
The compiler I'm using is gcc.
The section of the code related to this problem is:
        temp_number = (double)number / 10;
        number = trunc(temp_number);
        digit = (temp_number - number) * 10;

And the rest, for context, if it is needed:
bool get_checksum(long number, int number_lenght)
{
    bool checksum = 0;
    int total;
    int digit;
    double even = 0;
    double odd = 0;
    double temp_number;

    for (int i = 1; i <= number_lenght; i++)
    {
        temp_number = (double)number / 10;
        number = trunc(temp_number);
        digit = (temp_number - number) * 10;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            digit *= 2;
            even += digit / 10;
            even += ((float)digit / 10 - digit / 10) * 10;
        }
        else
        {
            odd += digit;
        }
    }
    total = even + odd;

    if (total % 10 == 0)
    {
        checksum = 1;
    }
    return checksum;
}


"it shows the correct values": how is this accomplished?

By "first" digit, you seem to mean the least-significant.  I would call that the last digit myself.  In any case, you're going to a lot more trouble than you need to do.  You can compute the least-significant decimal digit of an integer num directly, as num % 10.  You can read that as "num modulo 10", or as "the remainder of num divided by 10".

You are doing a Luhn calculation. Not only should you not be using floating-point, you should not be using an integer type for the credit card number. Read it as a string of digits, and then process each digit separately. When you try to read it as an integer, it may overflow. The long type is not guaranteed to be wide enough for credit card numbers.
